# validation error for RetrievalQA retriever value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)

Tags: python, langchain

I am trying to create  a custom filtered retriever to solve:
https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/14227

So my code is:

```
class FilteredRetriever:
    def __init__(self, retriever, title):
        self.retriever = retriever
        self.title = title

    def retrieve(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = self.retriever.retrieve(*args, **kwargs)
        return [doc for doc in results if doc['title'].startswith(self.title)]

filtered_retriever = FilteredRetriever(vector_store.as_retriever(), '25_1_0.pdf')

llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
    azure_deployment="chat",
    openai_api_version="2023-05-15",
)
    
retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(search_type="similarity",  kwargs={"k": 3})
chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(llm=llm,
                                    chain_type="stuff",
                                    retriever=filtered_retriever,
                                    return_source_documents=True)

result = chain({"query": 'Can Colleagues contact their managers??'})

for res in result['source_documents']:
    print(res.metadata['title'])
```

However I am getting this error:

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for RetrievalQA
retriever
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

Not sure what am I missing here: